# How to initialize char[] in a struct with constexpr char[] using initializer list?

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, initializer-list, construct

I have a struct like:

```
constexpr char defaultName[6] = "Hello";

struct MyStruct{
   char name[6];
   int val;
};
```

Now I want to initialize the struct using initializer list as following:

```
MyStruct structObj{defaultName, 0};
```

However, this doesn't work. How do I initialize the char array in initializer using `defaultName`?

I used `MyStruct structObj{defaultName, 0};` but this doesn't work. I know I can do `{"Hello", 0}` but I would like to use `constexpr`. Also, `strcpy` works but just wanted to know if there is a way to use the `defaultName` in initializer list.

Note: The struct is defined in a common library C header which is used by the C++ code so I can't update the struct definition.

Comment: plain old raw C arrays are not copyable.  If you are dealing with strings, you should use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays aren't copiable normally, but `std::array` is

```
constexpr std::array<char,6> defaultName {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};

struct MyStruct{
   std::array<char,6> name;
   int val;
};

MyStruct structObj{defaultName, 0};
```

If you can't update the struct, then use a default struct instead:

```
struct MyStruct{
   char name[6];
   int val;
};
constexpr MyStruct defaultStruct{"Hello",0};

MyStruct structObj(defaultStruct);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't update the struct to use modern c++ STL array due to some legacy thing. It has to be C-style array.

Comment: @DevG You can use `constexpr` but you can't use `std::array`?  The both started in the same version of C++, C++11.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you could create a helper function to initialize the C `struct`.

In C++17:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <std::size_t... Is>
constexpr MyStruct make_MyStruct_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                                        const char (&in)[sizeof...(Is)], int v) {
    return {{in[Is]...}, v};
}
}  // namespace detail

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr MyStruct make_MyStruct(const char (&in)[N], int v) {
    return detail::make_MyStruct_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), in, v);
}
```

In C++20 and later:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr MyStruct make_MyStruct(const char (&in)[N], int v) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return MyStruct{{in[Is]...}, v};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

---

Then used like this:

```cpp
constexpr char defaultName[6] = "Hello";

int main() {
    constexpr auto structObj = make_MyStruct(defaultName, 0);
    constexpr auto another = make_MyStruct("foo", 1);
}
```